# Why posterior variance approaches zero at the rate 1/n?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

We are discussing the binomial model with beta prior distribution. I don't know why it says which approaches zero at the rate 1/n?

[image]

Comment: $$
\frac{{\alpha  + y}}{{\alpha  + \beta  + n}} = \frac{\alpha }{{\alpha  + \beta  + n}} + \frac{n}{{\alpha  + \beta  + n}}\frac{y}{n} = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) + \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)\frac{y}{n} \sim \frac{y}{n}
$$ since $y/n$ is supposed to be large.

Comment: Note that the $x(1-x) \leq 0.25$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ so they can only claim that the variance will approach zero at least as fast as $0.25n$ (it can be much faster though).

Comment: @Gary Sorry, I don't understand your equation in terms of O.

Comment: @Mariana Study [asymptotic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).